# What do the tests of model effects and parameter estimates really tell (when an interaction is defined)?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, interaction, interpretation, generalized-estimating-equations

A couple of times in LMM or GEE (with SPSS, though I doubt that matters – and might occur in other analyses as well, but these are the ones with which I have seen it) I have seen something that seems contradictory: a continuous variable $X$ has completely different test values (Wald's or $F$s) and $p$s under tests of model effects and parameter estimates. For example, I have a GEE here with $p = .003$ for $X$ in tests of model effects, but $p = .728$ in parameter estimates:

[image]

I understand that these two $p$s for a categorical variable $Y$ can be different, as the tests of model effects check if any of the categories is different from zero, and if the reference category happens to be such that the estimate for category 1 is smaller and for category 2 bigger than the reference category, the estimates for those categories may not be different enough from the reference category (looking like I had no significant differences in parameter estimates) even if the difference between 1 and 2 would (which still shows in tests of model effects). This is clear. But I'm looking at a continuous variable now, with only one $b$ in parameter estimates that, if there were no interaction terms, has identical test values and $p$s with tests of model effects. However, when an interaction between $X$ and a categorical variable $Y$ is defined, the values may change wildly, and I don't know why.

I assume it happens only in interactions because the parameter is estimated when the other parameters are fixed to zero (continuous) or to the last category (categorical), and when an interaction $XY$ is defined, the estimates for categories of $Y$ affects the estimation of $X$ (as can seen by the fact that the estimates for $X$ change when the reference category for $Y$ is changed). If I had only $Y$ in the model, I could change the model so that the most extreme category is the reference, and I would see that the tests of model effects would be reasonably similar to tests of parameter estimates. But interactions seem to work different somehow. When I change the reference category for $Y$, the tests for parameter estimates for $Y$, $X$, and $XY$ change (for $X, p$ changes from $.103$ to mentioned $.728)$, but in the tests of model effects, only the effect for $X$ changes, and by a much lesser amount than in parameter estimates (between $.001$ and $.014)$.

1. Why does the test for model effect for $X$ change when the reference category is changed? If the tests of model effects indicates whether the variable as a whole is different from zero, the reference category shouldn't affect it (like it does not affect tests for model effects for $Y$ and $XY$).
2. And why are the test values and significances so different? How does it make sense that there is an effect for $X$ in the model, but when I try to find what it is, the estimate for the parameter is always so small that it is not different from zero? At the same time, the model effects for $Y$ and $XY$ seem much more consistent when compared to parameter estimates. What am I missing?

Comment: I gather this question is about interpreting SPSS output. Can you post an image of the output at issue? (Nb, CV may not let you, if so, you can post it to imgur & post a link here, then someone else can add them for you.) In general, when you have an interaction term (eg, X1*X2), the main effect is the change in Y associated w/ a change in X1 when X2=0.

Comment: Stupid me. I did not save that particular analysis, so I could not find the particular example I used above, but here's another one: http://imgur.com/hWVEEeB

Comment: i came across similar problems with GEE under SPSS. I guess this has something to do with problems during inversion. If you look carefully, you'll notice the notice "unable to compute due to numerical problems" and that no values are written for the intercept. So i guess this difference in p values arises from the computation issues. this might be due to multicolliniarity, but this is only a guess. have you mean centered the cont variable?

Comment: I have not mean centered cont. Should that help? I don't understand how.

Comment: It did not notify about any error, so I did not notice the notice.
I now tried a z-standardized cont, and the problem persists, although weaker (instead of .000 and .825 in the picture, I've got .118 and .533).
The description of multicollinearity (in Wikipedia) sounds like the problem I've got, but I only have one categorical and one continuous variable in the model. There's nothing to correlate. But I'll see about the suggestions in Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok, I now saw that one of the suggestions was mean centering and explained why that would matter. But yeah, didn't work.

Comment: @RandomMonitor did you find the answer to this question?